# Connect Windows PC to remote Linux serial port

Tags: networking, serial, com

I have a remote Linux(Ubuntu) server with embedded device connected to the server's serial port. I have a Windows program to manage that embedded device. Is any way to share server's serial port via Network and work with my embedded device with Windows program?

(Embedded dev)<-Serial->(Ubuntu server)<-Internet->(My Windows PC)

Comment: I guess you need to run `socat` on the Ubuntu Server, but I'm unable to give you more info about it. I haven't used it.

Comment: Can the Windoze program work with a device connected via your network?